# Error when using Requests with python 3.5 recursively (GooglePlaces API)

Tags: python, recursion, request, python-requests, google-places

I have been having a problem where I try to send a get request and if there is a next page token in the result it will then take that link and execute another request recursively until there is no next page token in the result.
The first request works fine but when there is a next page token in the response and it tries to execute the new request the result is an Invalid ReSponse but if I take the link that was given from the result and use it in postman or on my browser everything is fine.
I'm assuming it has something to requests running on different threads at the same time.

The second response from request using Python:

```
{'html_attributions': [], 'status': 'INVALID_REQUEST', 'results': []}
```

Here is what I have:

```
import requests 

def getPlaces(location,radius,type, APIKEY):

    url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location="+location+"&radius="+radius+"&type="+type+"&key="+APIKEY

    print('Getting results for type ' + type + '...')

    r = requests.get(url)

    response = r.json()

    results = []

    if response['status'] == 'ZERO_RESULTS':
        print("Did not find results for the type "+type)
    else:
        print("Results for type "+type)

        for result in response['results']:
            results.append(result)
            print(result)
    print('Printing results')
    print(results)

    if 'next_page_token' in response:
        print("There is a next page")
        page_token = response['next_page_token']
        print(page_token)
        next_results = getNextPlace(page_token,APIKEY)
        print(next_results)
        results.append(next_results)

    return results

    # Get the rest of the results


def getNextPlace(page_token,APIKEY):

    print('...')

    next_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location='+location+'&radius='+radius+'&type='+type+'&pagetoken=' + page_token + '&key=' + APIKEY

    print(next_url)
    r = requests.get(next_url)
    response = r.json()
    results = []
    print(response)

    if response['status'] == 'ZERO_RESULTS':
        print("Did not find results")
    elif response['status'] == 'INVALID_REQUEST':
        print('Invalid response')
    else:
        for next_result in response['results']:
             results.append(next_result)
             print(next_result)

    if 'next_page_token' in response:
        new_page_token = response['next_page_token']
        getNext = getNextPlace(new_page_token,APIKEY)
        results.append(getNext)

    return results
```

Answer (score 3):

Figured out the issue!
Google API doesn't allow consecutive requests to its API if the last request was within ~2 seconds.
What I did have I just had the program sleep for 3 seconds and the sent the request.
Now everything is working fine

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do can be seen in one function like:

```
def getPlaces(location,radius,API,i,type):
    url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location="+location+"&radius="+radius+"&key="+API+"&types="+type
    r = requests.get(url)
    response = r.json()
    results = []
    for result in response['results']:
        results.append(result)
    l=[]
    while True:
        if 'next_page_token' in response:
            page_token = response['next_page_token']
            l.append(page_token)
            next_url = url+'&pagetoken='+l[i]
            i=i+1
            time.sleep(3)
            r = requests.get(next_url)
            response = r.json()
            for next_result in response['results']:
                results.append(next_result)
        else:
            break
    return results
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code print "invalid response" because `response['status'] == 'INVALID_REQUEST'`, so it is google api service think your url request is invalid.

As [this document](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) says, the parameter location, radius, type and key is required, and the pagetoken is optional. So your second request url is invalid because it does not have the all required key.

Maybe you should try change the url to :

```
next_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location='+location+"&radius="+radius+"&type="+type+"&key="+APIKEY + "&pagetoken=" + page_token
```

Comment: I put that if statement just to make it look prettier.

Comment: What I get is {'html_attributions': [], 'status': 'INVALID_REQUEST', 'results': []}

Comment: I tried changing the url and I still get the same error

Comment: the documents said "INVALID_REQUEST generally indicates that a required query parameter (location or radius) is missing." I can not figure out why this error occurs, please refresh your code in your question. thx

Comment: I found the answer! The problem was that google places API doesn't allow consecutive requests to the API within ~2 seconds of the last request.